# How to remove the clicked span in Android in android?

Tags: android, spannablestring, clickablespan

I have implemented multiple clickable spans in a TextView.  My intention is to remove that paticular span which has been clicked. I am catching the onClick event of the span but it returns the whole textview. How do i isolate the span which was clicked and remove it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
String myText = "textA";
spannableStringBuilder = new SpannableStringBuilder(myText);
spannableStringBuilder.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {
        spannableStringBuilder.removeSpan(this);    // This will delete this clickable span
    }
},0,myText.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
myTextView.setText(spannableStringBuilder);
myTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```